# Connecting to local SQLite DB with pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, odbc, pyodbc

I have a database stored on my computer's disk, and I'm having trouble connecting to it with pyodbc.

I installed the SQLite3 ODBC Driver and got a DSN from my computer's Data Source Manager, and I then shortened it to the only values I thought I'd need, but it's worth noting that I get the same error with and without the rest of the values that come in the .dsn output file.

I get the error **('HY000', u'[HY000] connect failed (14) (SQLDriverConnect)')** on the following line of code...

(the actual path is omitted here and replaced with *path*)

`cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQLite3 ODBC Driver};Database={C:\*path*\example.db}')`

How do I go about connecting to the database here?

Comment: Python has [built-in support for SQLite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html). Is there a particular reason why you want to use pyodbc?

Comment: @GordThompson Yes. I am using example.db to test my script before using it with a different MS Access database that is already well-established in my workplace. I don't want to risk making any bad changes to the true database until my script is ready for it. SQLite was just the easiest way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The bare minimum connection string for SQLite ODBC would be

```py
conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;'
    r'DATABASE=C:\__tmp\SQLite\walmart.sqlite;'
)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
```

Verified with 32-bit sqlite3odbc.dll, version: 0.9998, on Windows 8.1.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work for me. I'm switching to MS Access, hopefully it will give me fewer issues. The final database I'll be working with is MS Access anyways, so it'll be easy to copy/paste the data, and likely easier to switch over when everything is said and done. Thanks for your help, anyways!